# A python socket client that outputs the source code of a website, why isn't this working?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, client

The following code doesn't output anything(why?).

```
#!/usr/bin/python           
import socket             

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 

s.connect(("www.python.org" , 80))
print s.recv(4096)
s.close()
```

What do I have to change in order to output the source code of the python website as you would see when you go to `view source` in a browser?

Comment: Don't work with the `socket` library; work with `urllib2` or better still `requests` (third party)

Comment: I want to understand networks in the lowest level using python. I want to be able to use any application layer protocol using only one python library. Also, I want to avoid too much dependence on external libraries. Why would you say that?

Comment: urllib2 is inbuilt in most version of python

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, I was talking about `requests` in my third sentence. But good to know it exists.

Comment: @Bentley4: as for understanding networks, `socket` isn't the lowest layer... it doesn't deal with the actual network interface or the link layer... anyway, if you're just trying to understand it, well and good, but in a real product, don't use `socket` where something else will suffice; other things have already dealt with the security issues and such. As for `requests`, I recommend it because it's got a nicer interface than `urllib2` and can be more capable when you get to more advanced situations.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Chris. I was only talking about python, I think using sockets is the lowest level to work with networking in python. Can you control the physical layer in python using another library? At least not as far as I know.

Comment: any real reason to use a lower level library? :/

Comment: Do you always know before you learn something that what you are going to learn is ever going to have some use or not? Some harder topics require you to invest at least some effort into understanding it in order to make that call. I've read that sockets are used a lot. Also, I like to understand how things work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is [request/response protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response). You're not sending any request, thus you're not getting any response.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 

s.connect(("www.python.org" , 80))
s.sendall("GET /\r\n") # you're missing this line
print s.recv(4096)
s.close()
```

Of course that will do the most raw HTTP/1.0 request, without handling HTTP errors, HTTP redirects, etc. I would **not** recommend it for actual usage beyond doing it as an exercise to familiarize yourself with socket programming and HTTP.

For HTTP Python provides few built in modules: [httplib](https://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) (bit lower level), [urllib](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (high level ones).

Comment: EJP: fixed. Also HTTP/1.1 request would be proper one, but I don't want to go into that much detail here.

Comment: and you probably need the `Host:` header

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: not in case of HTTP/1.0, neither for double `\r\n` nor `Host:`. You do need both for HTTP/1.1 requests.

Comment: @vartec: thx, found it http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Message (HTTP/0.9 messages)

Comment: Gross.  Use an HTTP client library.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get a redirect (302) unless you use the full URL in your request.

Try this instead:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 
s.connect(("www.python.org" , 80))
s.sendall("GET http://www.python.org HTTP/1.0\n\n")
print s.recv(4096)
s.close()
```

Of course if you just want the content of a URL this is far simpler. :)

```
print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org').read()
```

Comment: `GET /path`, not the full url... and you probably need the `Host:` header.

Answer (score 0):

I get the html with

```
    def steal_html():
        url='https://some_website.org'
        with open('index.html', 'w') as FILE:
            html = requests.get(url).text
            FILE.write(html)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30434675)